# Magic The Gathering Tactics on ATI M880G Mobility Radeon HD 4200?

Tags: technical-issues, windows, magic-the-gathering-tactics

This game won't run on anything with OpenGL lower than 2.1, and I have all the latest software from ATI installed and I get OpenGL 1.1

How can I update the OpenGL or get the game to run?

Comment: What driver version are you using?

Comment: Crap...I'll tell you tonight, I'm at work now and the laptop is home.

Comment: @Oscar 8.635.0.0 (8-4-2009)

Comment: One more thing: what OS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved! After days of downloading different drivers for my video card, I decided to start from scratch, so here's what I did:

1. Went to "Manage" system on the "My Computer" icon (right click for menu), and then "Device Manager"
2. Uninstalled the driver on my video device.
3. Restart and then go to AMD/ATI website to look for the new drivers.
4. Instead of downloading the 57MB file (the Catalyst Control), I downloaded a 935KB file that scans your system and decides the best driver. So this downloaded the correct driver and voila! all fixed!

Now Tactics and Duels of the Planeswalkers are working great and I got OpenGL 3.3 :D

Comment: Yeah, I was about to say that you should download the Catalyst drivers (currently ver. 11.5), but glad you solved it.